# document.addEventListener not working on loaded svg

Tags: javascript, svg, addeventlistener

I'm trying to build a project in which the user can click on an image and then an interactive .svg is loaded (inside an object tag). For that, I need to track the mouse movement on the entire screen (not only the .svg) after the loading has happened.

However, neither document.addEventListener nor window.addEventListener seem to work on the .svg. They just work outside its boundaries. Is there a way to fix this without having to combine document.addEventListener and the specific interactiveSVG.addEventListener?

Here is my code (edited):

```
let firstImage = document.querySelector('#my-first-img');
let objectSVG = document.querySelector('#svg-obj');
let interactiveSVG;

firstImage.addEventListener('click', e => {
        objectSVG.data = `mySVG.svg`;
        objectSVG.addEventListener('load', e => {
            interactiveSVG = objectSVG.getSVGDocument();
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
                console.log(e.clientX);
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: what is `firstImage`, `objectSVG` and `interactiveSVG` - any errors in the browser console? - perhaps add a `error` handler on loading the svg, to handle errors

Comment: Your script needs to run with `defer` or in/after `DOMContentLoaded`.

Comment: I just edited the code to include the declarations. firstImage is the first clickable image (like a button), objectSVG is the object in the HTML that includes the SVG after it is loaded, and interactiveSVG is the svg file. I don't get any error in the console. It prints correctly the X coordinate as it changes when the pointer is outside the loaded svg, but when I'm on the svg the console doesn't print any message.

Comment: One possible answer is that the image has no fill.  Can you add the code of the svg or a simplified version of it?

Comment: @Dai Thanks for the reply. I tried both defer and DOMContentLoaded, however they didn't work for me. Probably that's due to other parts of my code that deal with interactivity of the svg.

Comment: @enxaneta I checked the fill atttribute and both with and without it it didn't work. In the end I am adopting an approach similar to that suggested below by zer00ne. But thank you for answering to my question.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, a SVG within an `<object>` limits you somewhat. There are exstensive features for the [CSS property `pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pointer-events) that can apply to [SVG elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element#svg_elements_a_to_z), which unfortanately an `<object>` cannot provide. But if you assign `pointer-events: none` to the SVG it'll be ignored so pointer events will fire directly over the SVG but the `event.target` will be the closest ancestor DOM element of the SVG.

For SVG in `<object>`, you need an actual `<style>` tag within the `<object>` and add `pointer-events: none`:

```
<object class="map" data="path/to/image.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
  <style>
    .map {
      pointer-events: none;
    }
  </style>
</object>
```

The example below demonstrates normal pointer behavior when hovering over or clicking on the SVG. Keep in mind with `pointer-events: none`, what is actually happening is all interactions are in the DOM.

**Usage**

- Hover over the entire page and observe the XY coords displayed in the lefthand corner. The SVG is outlined in a red dashed line, note that mousemove events fire when the cursor is over the SVG.
- Click outside and inside of the SVG. There will be a flag icon set at every click (hover over a flag and a hint will popup with it's XY coords). This is possible because each flag is `position: absolute` and the `body` is `position: relative`.

Note: the coords of the flgs and the coods displayed in the corner are not exact because the flags are on a offset of `.getBoundingClientRect()` measurements and `clientX/Y`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <style>
    html {
      font: 1.5ch/1 Consolas;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    fieldset {
      width: max-content;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    mark {
      position: absolute;
      background: transparent;
    }
    
    mark:after {
      content: '\1f6a9';
      font-size: 1.25rem;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <fieldset>
    <legend><output class="view"></output></legend>
    <object class="map" data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Simple_world_map.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
          <style>
            .map {
              transform: scale(0.75);
              outline: 1px dashed red;
              pointer-events: none;
            }
          </style>
        </object>
  </fieldset>
  <script>
    document.onmousemove = trackPoint;
    document.onclick = markPoint;

    function trackPoint(e) {
      const view = document.querySelector('.view');
      view.value = `X: ${e.clientX.toString().padStart(3, '0')} : Y: ${e.clientY.toString().padStart(3, '0')}`;
    }

    function markPoint(e) {
      const mark = document.createElement('mark');
      document.body.appendChild(mark);
      getCoords.call(mark, e);
    }

    function getCoords(e) {
      const clk = e.target;
      const rect = clk.getBoundingClientRect();
      const oX = Math.floor(e.clientX - rect.left);
      const oY = Math.floor(e.clientY - rect.top);
      this.style.left = oX + 'px';
      this.style.top = oY + 'px';
      this.title = `[${oX}, ${oY}]`;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I actually thought that <object> was the best way of embedding external svgs. Your answer could solve my problem, but it seems to me that I would lose on interactivity with my svg. So in the end (for those who may read this in the future) based on your answer I chose to copy dynamically my external svg in a svg tag and interact with the latter (my svg is pretty simple and light). It works and I can use also pointer events, which I didn't know about before. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, yeah I like how responsive SVG is, but it's so complex. `<object>` has been my goto when I do use SVG on a rare occasion.